# Windows Domain controller recover test

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, system-restore

I'm testing a Exchange 2012 VM recovery in a Hyper-V test server.
I have this VM, 2 DC and a Exchange server:

- SRVDC1 (pdc, nm, rid)
- SRVDC2
- SRVEX2

As far as I know I need to recover also a Domain Controller to let exchange run, then I choose to recover only SRVDC2 (non-pdc) to simulate a pdc failure. This DC cannot start the AD services, DNS and so on... maybe because it is not syncronized with its pdc.
Is there some way to run the non-pdc domain controller alone?

**EDIT:**
I also tried to seize roles from dead DC1 to DC2, but AD services and DNS doesn't start.

Comment: I've been in situations where this has happened in a live environment and exchange continued to run.

Comment: But I think that Exchange will fails at restart... am I right?

Comment: Anything in the event logs, like words or numbers?

Comment: As long as the the second DC starts, exchange will work.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both Global Catalog servers (and the respective AD DC Roles), both have DNS  and Exchange is configured to point to both DNS servers, I can't see there being an issue.

Comment: I don't know why, however the DC2 after a reboot without its PDC doesn't start AD services and DNS. I also tried to seize all roles to DC2 (so now it is the PDC) but it fails again to start services.... for example if I run netdom query fmso I get "specified domain either does not exists or could not be contacted"

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue make sure your NIC DNS are set to itself and the other domain controller.

Also have a look in the event logs for AD DC errors.